# Installing of WebP, conan errror

Tags: python, pycharm, data-science, webp, conan

I'm trying to install webp in PyCharm, but after

```
'pip install webp'
```

i get this error:
[image]

Please, help me. I've been trying to install webp for a few days and have already lost all hope. I just don't know what to do. Thanks for all advices!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the `webp` Python package requires Conan C/C++ package manager to build itself from sources: https://github.com/anibali/pywebp, it is a binding over that package.

Conan will use when necessary to build from sources (https://conan.io/center has many pre-compiled binaries for many platforms) a C/C++ compiler in your machine. It will try to auto-detect it and define the `default` profile file that will contain definitions for `compiler`, `compiler.version` and other configuration.

In this case, it seems you don't have a working compiler in your system, I would try to install in Windows the free Visual Studio Community, which is the mainstream C/C++ compiler.

I would also suggest to report an issue in https://github.com/anibali/pywebp/issues, and ask for an update, there are now new versions of libwebp C++ library in https://conan.io/center/libwebp, which will be more supported and maintained.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your response. I have installed Visual Studio (2017, it works, C++ programs compile), but it doesnt help. I've also created an issue in github, now i'm waiting for a help from them. Dont even know, what i do wrong

Comment: https://github.com/anibali/pywebp/issues/20 here is an answer